# Getting syntax error in field definition while altering table of ms access using vb .net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to alter a table and add multiple columns to my table but I am getting error

> syntax error in field definition

I am working with vb.net and MS Access 2013.

Here is my code:

```
cmd.Connection = con

cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Game_Player ADD QUESTIONS TEXT(50),USER_ANSWER TEXT(10),TIME TEXT(10),SECOND (10),lbl_Lock TEXT(10),lbl_vis TEXT(10)"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I don't think you can add multiple columns in 1 alter table statement. [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Also, you are hitting on some reserved words [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335)

Comment: so what i have to do to add multiple columns at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access SQL does support adding multiple columns with one `ALTER TABLE` statement.

The field definition error likely occurs due to the lack of a data type for the `SECOND` field.  However two of the column names, `SECOND` and `TIME`, are  [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html). (Also see the [link @Andrew provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465442/getting-syntax-error-in-field-definition-while-altering-table-of-ms-access-using#comment58626794_35465442).)  Those names may also trigger errors, but it's not always easy to predict when they will cause trouble. The safest alternative would be to choose column names which are not reserved words.  If you must keep those names, bracket them in your SQL statement ...

```sql
ALTER TABLE Game_Player
ADD COLUMN
    QUESTIONS TEXT(50),
    USER_ANSWER TEXT(10),
    [TIME] TEXT(10),
    [SECOND] TEXT(10),
    lbl_Lock TEXT(10),
    lbl_vis TEXT(10)
```

I included the `COLUMN` keyword and assumed `TEXT` as the data type for `SECOND`.